# Creating two div Dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create two div in one function and i am not able to figure out how to do it.
I have created on div dynamically and was trying to create two div in one function.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `insertAfter()` function in native javascript, here is how you can create the funcitons for various same work.

```
//create the passed element with id and class
function createElement(tag, id, className){
    var elem = document.createElement(tag);
    if(typeof id != 'undefined'){
        elem.id = id;
    }

    if(typeof className != 'undefined'){
        elem.className = className;
    }

    return elem;
}

//create div and submit tag with passed id and class
function createDivs() {
    var divTag = createElement('div', 'textarea', 'divdrag');
    var textAreaElm = createElement('textarea', 'myTextarea', 'textarea');
    divTag.appendChild(textAreaElm);
    par = document.getElementById('stage');
    insertAfter(par, divTag);

    createDiv(par, 'insertAfter');
    //put insertBefore--^---here when you need insertBefore to append
}

//create div and it's child button
function createDiv(par, where){
    var divTag = createElement('div', 'submit', 'divdrag');

    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Submit");
    btn.className = "btn";
    btn.appendChild(t);
    divTag.appendChild(btn);
    if(where == 'insertAfter'){
        insertAfter(par, divTag);
    }else if(where == 'insertBefore'){
        par.insertBefore(divTag, par.firstChild);
    }
}

//insertAfter function as there is no native support by js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

createDivs();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z74Fr/)

Comment: Is there any way i can show createDiv along with createDivs function instead of creating it again?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i was looking for. Yo are a gem . :)

Comment: Please post it into site, will definitely look it.